# MongoDB select all keys with null value

Tags: mongodb

For example, my documents are like:

```
{key1: value, key2: value}
{key1: value, key3: value}
{key1: value, key3: value, key4: value}
```

I want return a collection of results like:

```
{key1: value, key2: value, key3: null, key4: null}
{key1: value, key2: null, key3: null, key4: null}
{key1: value, key2: null, key3: value, key4: value}
```

I don't know if MongoDB can return this kind of json result using some kind of query?
I want to present the document in a tabular form, the null would be blank in a table cell.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to be filter it the database,seems easier to just pad it before rendering  the table. IMHO no point of imposing a schema on a  schema-less db

instead grab things as they come and so something like (mongoid)

```
<table>

    <%=row.each do |r| %>
    <tr>
    <% r.fields.each do |f,v| %>
    <%val = r.send(f) || "n/a"%>
    <td><%=val %></td>
    <%end%>
    </tr>
    <%end%>
    </table>
```

Edit: Based on valuable comment below i took out the link to the JS implementation
It's best to deal with the data in the higher layers. My original point still stands though, just check if you get meaningful data (as you should anyways) and render accordingly

Comment: Even though yours is the best answer here that link ruins the answer, it is extremely bad practice to do as that guy shows and the JS engine has numerous flaws not only that but it isn't a, server-side and b, stored procedure.

Comment: Sorry didn't really read into, i just found it and thought it may work :/ Shouldn't have posted but i wanted to give something in JS as well as ruby since the OP asked about pure mongo

Comment: Yea understandable, I just get a little itchy from that link due to how many people actually believe it :)